# Can iterative merge sort be used to count inversions?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I know that recursive merge sort works well to count inversions.
For example if I want to count the number of smaller elements on the right of the current element, would iterative merge sort work like recursive does?
For example:

```
[5,2,6,1] -> [2,1,1,0] 
5 has smaller elements on the right [2,1]
2 has 1 smaller element on the right [1]
6 has 1 smaller element on the right [1]
1 has no smaller elements on the right
```

Comment: Why not? It is an algorithm, not implementation which counts.

Comment: If recursive works iterative should also work.

Comment: The comparisons that take place are different.

Comment: Assuming that the inversion count is done in the merge function, it doesn't matter if the merge function is being called from a top down recursive or bottom up iterative merge sort function. Either way, the array ends up sorted, and you end up with a valid inversion count.